# Word for people easily influenced by propaganda

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that describes people who are easily influenced by propaganda or always do what all other people are seen to be doing without much thinking?

Comment: According to psychologists and social psychologists, the more educated you are, the less susceptible you **think** you are, but, in fact, they claim it's quite the opposite. People who are educated are generally more open-minded than the ignorant & ill-educated, so they're more influenced by propaganda than the closed-minded. People who "always do what all other people are seen to be doing without much thinking" are called "conformists" & "well-adjusted members of society". Your fellow parishioners, for example; your fraternity brothers; your military or corporate colleagues; etc.

Comment: At least in me experience, most of them are called "salesmen". The defining characteristic of being a good salesman is being susceptible to your own propaganda (which usually translates to being susceptible others' propaganda as well).

Comment: @user21497 can you cite a source?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, If we're throwing words around, I'd like to throw in *credulous*.

Answer (score 9):

I know of no word quite so specific, but *gullible* describes anyone who is easily fooled.

Answer (score 3):

What about *uncritical* or *accepting*?

Answer (score 3):

The succinct word - in fact the singular word for which the question is the exact definition of, is:

SUGGESTIBLE

A suggestible person is someone easily influenced by propaganda.

Answer (score 2):

**Conformist / conforming** - has the strong connotation of someone who "goes along" but not of that being a bad thing. One might (rightly) conform to a law one doesn't happen to like, or (wrongly) conform to a mob's violence or social injustice.

**Suggestible** - someone who takes on thoughts and ideas from others without conscious consideration

**Susceptible (to propaganda)** - can be influenced/affected

**Influenceable (by propaganda)** - as above

**Malleable** - bendable, implies resistance on some level that is ultimately suspended. The analogy is to metalworking.

**Compliant** - someone who complies over-readily

**Sheepish** - used in a certain sense, it means someone who follows a herd mentality. It can also mean shy or cowardly.

**Lemming** - (noun) means someone who follows a crowd even suicidally

Comment: To me, ["they are sheepish"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22they+are+sheepish%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) would normally mean *embarrassed/bashful*. It's ["they are **sheep**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22they+are+sheep%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) that I see as embodying OP's *credulous, easily-led* sense.

Comment: Fair enough. I think my use still works, though. http://www.wordreference.com/thesaurus/sheepish

Comment: Of course. I don't mean to say "sheepish" is *never* used with that sense. It's just that the distinction I made applies more often than not, but this would not be clear from your wording.

Comment: Fair enough, @FumbleFingers.

Answer (score 2):

The word I always think of first when someone is easily influenced or persuaded is "impressionable"

Comment: Hello, Name, and welcome to English Language & Usage. This is an excellent suggestion in my opinion; but to make your answer more self-contained, please consider adding a relevant definition for _impressionable_ from a reliable dictionary. This will corroborate your answer and help readers who aren't familiar with the precise meaning of the word see at once why it works here. If you make the additional effort, I'll happily upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

["Sukka"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/440252/191178) was the closest word to the definition.  Too bad it is slang.  Maybe "propagandized."  (ex.:  The propagandized buy into the fake news, without questioning the lack of names or evidence.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to throw my entry into the ring. 'Weak Minded'. Wikipedia says for Weak Minded "... is the state of being easily impressionable or possessing a weak sense of self-will, judgement or conviction.

A weak minded individual's opinion may be easily swayed by propaganda or emotional manipulation tactics, as they do not possess an adequate ability to judge or discern the quality of an assertion, or they may exhibit a lack of discipline."

Answer (score 1):

**Apart from those that have already been suggested, I can think of-**

1. Naïve
2. Ingenuous

**Very simple ones but worthy of mention-**

3. Childish
4. Innocent
5. Inexperienced

**If you’re trying to insult someone-**

6. Ignorant
7. Silly
8. Foolish

**Slightly poetic-**

9. Green
10. As green as grass

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please feel free to take the Tour and [visit the Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) on how to prepare good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Final Answer:  **SUCKA** 
                    noun  /SUK-Kuh/
Definition of SUKKA: Easily swayed, duped, easy target, no original opinions, dumbass, `patsy`. (syn.)

Ex. - "I sold that SUKKA 3 gold chains.  He found out they were fake, wanted his skrilla back, so I doubled it to 6 gold chains and he took it!'

REf: URBAN DICTIONARY

Comment: This looks like quoted content from Urban Dictionary. Please provide the link with your answer, and use block quotes to show what part you wrote and what is from Urban Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Sheeple** wasn't in the dictionary when this question was asked, but it is now; and the word has been around since 1945.

> informal
> : people who are docile, compliant, or easily influenced : people likened to sheep

Merriam Webster:[sheeple](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheeple)

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer the word fickle minded for this.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." :)