# What do you call someone who is easily influenced?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for a term with bad connotation. I am aware of the popular terms like "he/she has no personality", pliable, malleable, weak-minded but i couldn't find any more on the insulting side. It could be an idiom or a single word.

For example:

> - I just bought this bag yesterday and he came today with a new
>   one too
> - He never talks to her and now he does –just because I did in the morning. He is such a ____

Comment: How is that person easily influenced? Does (s)he believe everything people say? Can you show us an example sentence where the word/phrase would be used with context? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Rathony I added examples.

Comment: Both the examples look more like "slavish copycat" than what I'd normally think of as "easily influenced", since in both cases it's unlikely the speaker actually *intended* to influence the [toady?, sycophant?].

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are right this is a not intended influence

Comment: Perhaps [*impulsive*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/impulsive)? He is so **impulsive**.

Comment: In some contexts (he only bought his wife champagne & a single rose for her birthday because he knew ***I*** did that last month for my wife) you might say he's just ***unimaginative***.

Comment: By the way, the usual idiom in English is "What do you call [something]," not "How do you call [something]." See this question: [How do you call..? vs. What do you call…?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324568/how-do-you-call-vs-what-do-you-call)

Comment: @sumelic You are right, my mistake.

Comment: Not mentioned so far: **pushover** comes to mind.

Answer (score 5):

These seem to fit your criteria:

**impressionable** - easily influenced because of a lack of critical ability.

**susceptible** - likely or liable to be influenced or harmed by a particular thing.

Note these words fit your title and description much better than they do your examples.

Answer (score 2):

Consider credulous. While this is not necessarily a term with a bad connotation, it can be considered a negative attribute. Here's another post asking for a similar word: [Word for people easily influenced by propaganda](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93651/word-for-people-easily-influenced-by-propaganda)

Answer (score 2):

Try a thesaurus search on **Gullible** or **Follower**

Some words you might like are Patsy, Sucker, Lemming, Sheeple, Lackey, Flunkey, Copycat, Follower, Aper, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In a TED talk about male-female relationships, I heard the host, a native English speaker, use the term 'influenceable', as in 'Men must be influenceable to make good fathers', or something like that.
However, in the examples you gave, I feel a negative connotation is called for because these sentences do describe a copycat! :)