# A word for a person who is easily influenced by movies?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What can we call a person who is easily influenced by movies or whatever he reads on websites like `Quora` without even thinking if the content he is reading is valid or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call someone who is easily influenced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/326907/what-do-you-call-someone-who-is-easily-influenced)

Comment: The nominated duplicate is certainly related, but that explicitly asks for pejorative terms. This question might usefully have answers which are more neutral.

Comment: We have guidelines for single word requests. Please review them and edit your question accordingly (unless the marked duplicate is sufficient).

Answer (score 1):

Impressionable? I don't think English gets that specific, maybe I'm wrong, impressionable means, easily influenced.